# Community ads for other sites!

Tags: discussion

Could some artistic people put together some quality community ads to put on other sites?

I'd recommend

[Sci-Fi Community Ads](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/991/community-promotion-ads-2012)
[Roleplaying Community ads](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1497/community-promotion-ads-2012)
and
[Gaming/Arqade Community Ads](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3352/community-promotion-ads-2012)

So what do people think? Can we do this?

Comment: Just remember that community ads on other sites must be relevant to their audience! In this case, I think the audiences there would find BCG of interest, but it's worth keeping in mind. :) When in doubt, pop into the site chatroom and ask.

Comment: I actually came here looking for an ad to put on [rpg.se] .. so if you guys have something...

Comment: @Tritium21 nope not while we're in beta....

Comment: @Pureferret why wouldn't there be advertising in beta?  The only other stack advertised on [RPG.se] is [worldbuilding.se] which is also beta... it helps the beta stacks.  I am confused.

Comment: @Tritium21 OH! Put ad ON. Got you. Well Yes you can make one for BGSE, and put it else where. Also, please do so for the more up to date post.

Answer (score -3):

[image: Board & Card Games Stackexchange]

Comment: That looks like it's just a cropped image of the Small World: River World board, with the site logo on top of it. It is not appropriate to use a copyrighted image for an advertisement like this.

Comment: Boards are copyrighted?

Comment: @cazc_941 Creative artworks, such as those features on a board game's board, are copyrighted.

Comment: Looks like it needs attribution. I can edit that in when I get home from work, I guess.  https://boardgamegeek.com/image/3157891/small-world-river-world